# Reversing my MergeSort Algorithm

Tags: c#, algorithm, mergesort

Basically I've got a merge sort in my code to order a group of numbers in a text file. I've given the option through a menu to allow the user to sort these numbers in ascending and descending order. At the moment I only have it one way and I can't for the life of me figure out how to reverse it. It's probably something really simple. Here's my code:

Methods

```
static public void mergemethod(int [] numbers, int left, int mid, int right)
    {
        int [] temp = new int[144];
        int i, left_end, num_elements, tmp_pos;
        left_end = (mid - 1);
        tmp_pos = left;
        num_elements = (right - left + 1);
        while ((left <= left_end) && (mid <= right))
        {
            if (numbers[left] <= numbers[mid])
                temp[tmp_pos++] = numbers[left++];
            else
                temp[tmp_pos++] = numbers[mid++];
        }
        while (left <= left_end)
            temp[tmp_pos++] = numbers[left++];
        while (mid <= right)
            temp[tmp_pos++] = numbers[mid++];
        for (i = 0; i < num_elements; i++)
        {
            numbers[right] = temp[right];
            right--;
        }

    }
    static public void sortmethod(int [] numbers, int left, int right)
    {
      int mid;
      if (right > left)
      {
        mid = (right + left) / 2;
        sortmethod(numbers, left, mid);
        sortmethod(numbers, (mid + 1), right);
        mergemethod(numbers, left, (mid+1), right);

      }
    }
```

Where it's used.

```
private static void SortVolume(int sortingAD)
    {
        if (sortingAD == 1)
        {
            int[] numbers = Array.ConvertAll(Volume, int.Parse);
            int len = 144;
            Console.WriteLine("\nAscending order: To return, press any key");
            sortmethod(numbers, 0, len - 1);
            for (int i = 0; i < 144; i++)
                Console.WriteLine(numbers[i]);
        }
        else if (sortingAD == 2)
        {
            //This is where the reverse code will go(?)
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
        MainMenu(true);
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: sorting became very easy and readable with the release of Linq. For example sorting an array of int is as simple as : `var sortedList = myIntArray.ToList().OrderBy(i=>i).ToList()` or descending `var sortedList = myIntArray.ToList().OrderByDescending(i=>i).ToList()`. You will need to add the following using : `using System.Linq;`

Comment: You can always sort it in ascending order using your method if you prefer that and reverse the result with [`Array.Reverse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d3877932%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Somewhere you will have to compare two elements, i think it's this line: `if (numbers[left] <= numbers[mid])`. Here you can just use the not operator `!` if you need the reverse order. If you need stableness, then you should also care for the "equal" case.

Comment: @Franck - While LINQ is very handy for sorting a list, it uses a different algorithm QuickSort. This algorithm has different properties than a mergesort, so it can be an alternative or not.